# Direct Data Validation with IFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an ifs statement that works with data validation.
I want it to be

```
IFS(A1="Location1","Fred",A1="Location2","Mike",A1="Location3", *drop down of 3 names*)
```

- If A1= Location 1 then A2 autopopulates to Fred,
- same with location 2 and Mike,
- Location 3 I want a drop down of 3 names in A2

Any ideas on how it would be able to work?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot have a formula AND a drop down list.  You will need vba to do this in a worksheet_change event.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have shown a drop down with a vlookup and a dropdown to pick a location which then allows the second dropdown to have the correct names using index & match:

[image]

Cell A1 has the dropdown for location based on F1:F4.

Cell A6 had a dropdown based on cells F6:H6

Cell A8 the dropdown using cells C8:C10.

Two methods that you may carve-up as you wish.