# How can I make a cell in the sheet dropdown list with receive multiple values? (multiple selection)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

Found in the gem (write_xlsx) how to make the cell be a dropdown list but receive one value .... What I want is how to make the cell a dropdown list with the ability to choose more than one value

Comment: Data validation can take a list, either as items typed in or a range of cells (row or column).

Comment: yes but i can select single value only,  
i want select multiple selection

Comment: Then have the cells that Data Validation references collect info from another range of cells. Use choose() is one option. An answer doing that is on here.

Comment: See this and give it a vote if it helps. Two methods shown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56226057/4961700

Comment: i did that ... i made info are collect from another cell range... but no avail